# How to forward port on running vagrant box

Tags: networking, docker, vagrant, virtual-machine, port

I have multiple docker containers running in vagrant box exposing various ports, but I forgot to forward these ports in Vagrantfile. Is it possible to forward the necessary ports without rebooting the machine (initializing all those containers would take a long while) and if not, what is the fastest method in that case?

Is there some organized way to handle port mappings in vagrant? It is pain to know all the needed ports beforehand. Especially when you must add new service to already running docker network inside vagrant, you would have to stop everything just to expose a port on vagrant host. And how to deal with situation where docker chooses random port from it's host for port forwarding? Is this just precluded when using vagrant? All feels so fragile to even little change.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. you will need to do it directly from VirtualBox

1. Open VirtualBox
2. Edit the settings of the VM you want to change
3. Go to the Network tab
4. Go to advanced then Forwarding Rules (or port forwarding, I got french version of vbox not sure whats the exact translation)
5. Add your custom rules
6. Apply

The forwarding rules is applied and you can connect to the guest port from your host

Comment: Do you have some point of view, how to keep port forwarding organized when working with vagrant and docker? Is it really the only choice to know all the necessary ports beforehand, if working with vagrant API is only option to manage vm?

Comment: in many cases while working with vagrant I prefer to use a private network with a static IP and call it with the IP so I dont need to hande port forwarding. but when needed yep its a mess if you forgot one (when adding a new soft or something) in many of my cases though reload of the VM is quick enough when its needed

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to open a terminal tab and run `vagrant ssh` with the ssh options needed to set up a tunnel. This is only temporary, so you still need to add the port forwarding to your `Vagrantfile` if you want it to persist.

```
vagrant ssh -- -L 5000:localhost:5000
```

This forwards port 5000 on the guest to port 5000 on the host.